# How to validate my windows forms in C#

Tags: c#, forms

How do I validate my windows forms in C#?

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: Please post what code you have, and what you want to do.  Your form code would be a good starting point.

Answer (score 3):

Look into [ErrorProvider Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.errorprovider.aspx). I am assuming here that you are trying to validate   form controls.

1. [How to: Display Error Icons for Form Validation with the Windows Forms ErrorProvider Component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f6xht7x2.aspx)
2. [Extending Windows Forms with a Custom Validation Component Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950965.aspx)
3. [Validating TextBox](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/validatingtextbox.aspx)
4. [Link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/books/1861004982.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

If you're looking for simple text value or checkbox checking, such as in a login form or acceptance of terms of services, you can use something like:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text == "check text" &&
            textBox2.Text == "check another field" &&
            checkBox1.Checked)
        {
            //perform actions
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Your input failed validation.");
        }
    }
```

Where button1 is the submit button, and textBox1, textBox2, and checkBox1 are various fields that are being validated.

Comment: You are bypassing the use of `OnValidating` and `OnValidated` events for controls.